# Submit Flink job detached in session model cluster , but Flink Cli will not return after showing the job id

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface, apache-flink, submit

I'm using Flink cli to submit a detached job in session model Flink cluster ,it success and showed the job id , but cli would not return and block the console.

My docker-compose file segment:

```
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.15.3-scala_2.12-java8
    logging: *default-logging
    network_mode: host
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
    - /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai:/etc/localtime
    - ./libs:/opt/flink/lib/libs
    - ./jobmanager/processWorkDir:/processWorkDir
    - ./jobmanager/checkpointsDir:/checkpointsDir
    - ./jobmanager/savepointsDir:/savepointsDir
    - ./jobmanager/jobs:/opt/flink/usrlib
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        process.working-dir: /processWorkDir
        jobmanager.rpc.address: 10.0.9.75
        jobmanager.host: 10.0.9.75
        state.backend: rocksdb
        state.checkpoints.dir: file:///checkpointsDir/
        state.checkpoint-storage: filesystem
        state.savepoints.dir: file:///savepointsDir/
        execution.checkpointing.interval: 60000
```

My java code just like

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnvironment = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, streamSettings);
tableEnvironment.executeSql("create TEMPORARY table source_table ....");
tableEnvironment.executeSql("create TEMPORARY table redis_sink ....");
final TableResult sinkResult = tableEnvironment.executeSql("insert into redis_sink select * from source_table");

sinkResult.print();
env.execute("test job");
```

My command just like：

```bash
docker-compose exec jobmanager /opt/flink/bin/flink run --detached -t remote -m 10.0.9.75:8081 -c com.test.TestJob /opt/flink/usrlib/dev2/test-0.0.1-RELEASE.jar
```

I had use --detached option. but the command never return after showed the job id, Althougth the job graph had been created successfully, I can use Ctrl+C to break the command and job still running well for hours , but what I want is use this command in my CI pipeline, I need the command show the job id and return normally。

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use `nohup` to run the deploy command line。